# How to verify that a user's time is true and is not spoofing an app in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nstimer

I would like to verify if an app user has not messed around with the time settings to spoof transaction times on my trading app. I am using Firestore as my database. What would be the smartest way to go about it?

Comment: Seems to me like the smartest way would be to not use a client-provided time for anything critical like that.

Comment: Yes, you should use time from a server somewhere. Ideally you wouldn't allow the app to enter a trade into Firebase directly, but rather submit a transaction to a server function with the server adding the time to the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure you can trust the timestamp, is to [use Firestore's built in server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). From the documentation:

> ```
> db.collection("objects").document("some-id").updateData([
>     "lastUpdated": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
> ])
> ```

If you can't use the server timestamp, you can use Firestore's server-side security rules to at least ensure that the timestamp that the client passes is within a reasonable range. To do so compare the built-in [`request.time` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) with the value that the client specified.